# Javascript conflicting countdown

Tags: javascript, time, timer, alert, countdown

Thanks in advance for reading this post. Please go to http://www.hostmarts.com/projanmo/iftar_alert.html where I have written a JS. It's OK with the countdown in red digits when page loads. It is also ok with the countdown when I change the zone for the first time. However, there is a problem when I change the zone second time and onwards.

Is there any solution? You can see the code by viewing the page source.

Thanks

Zelal

Comment: I have solved the problem. Just removed the setInterval function from zone onchange function and modified a little the onload setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will most likely be caused by using setIntervall in line 165. Changing the time zone doesn't stop the "old" intervall, which makes the time count down. After a few changes of the timezone there are multiple intervall timers manipulating your time.

But I'd say that is not your real problem! You shouldn't create your DOM-elements purely in javascript but you should use html for the basic design. Also you should use style sheets instead of defining your style in your javascript code.

Maybe you want to take a look again at some basic HTML/CSS and JS tutorials to get a feeling how to structure your code to make it readable and maintainable.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make a userscript. So, I need to generate some HTML elements on the fly. However, many thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Also, I tried to stop previous onchange countdown by: clearInterval(onchange_countdown); But, it did NOT work. Don't know why.